# bootstrap form input fields alignment

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the below code

```
<form id="editProfileForm" class="form-horizontal span8"  method="post">  
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputSubject">Subject</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="inputSubject" class="span8" >
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputTags">Tags</label>
        <div class="controls">                            
            <input type="text" id="inputTags" class="span3">  
        </div>        
    </div> 

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputAccess">access</label>
        <div class="controls">                            
            <input type="text" id="inputAccess" class="span3">  
        </div>        
    </div>
```

I am getting the form like below [image]

Could some one suggest me how to get like below ? Thanks for your help

[image]

JS Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/kLuB3/331/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`form-inline` would be better suited for this than `form-horizontal`.

Try this:

```
<form id="editProfileForm" class="span8 form-inline" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span1" for="inputSubject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputSubject" class="span7">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span1" for="inputTags">Tags</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputTags" class="span3">
        <label class="span1" for="inputAccess" id="inputAccessLabel">access</label>
        <input type="text"id="inputAccess" class="span3">
    </div>
</form>
```

With this CSS:

```
#inputTags, #inputAccess {
    float: left !important;
}
#inputAccessLabel {
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLuB3/335/)